# How to add a new "fixed" value row into a table

Tags: excel, activex

I'm working on an excel spreadsheet for personal monthly finance. My question is can you create an ActiveX Button that will add a fixed row to the bottom of a table when pressed?

The table looks like this:

```
Date         Description    Amount     Account
10/2/2017    Rent           $440.00    Checking(NF) 
10/3/2017    Groceries                 Checking(TD) 
10/3/2017    Transfer       $140.00    Checking(NF) 
10/3/2017    Transfer       ($140.00)  Credit Card(NF)
```

I was looking to add a fixed row of:
`=TODAY() Rent $440.00 Checking(NF)` to the bottom of the table above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code. You could add a command button to the sheet with the pivot and associate the button with the following code:

```
Sub FindTableLastRow()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim lRow As Long
Dim startCol As String * 1
Dim AddressArr() As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(2) 'Adjust this to your sheet name with the table in.
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1") 'Adjust to your table name

AddressArr = Split(tbl.Range.Address, "$")   
startCol = AddressArr(1)
lRow = AddressArr(4)

ws.Cells(lRow + 1, startCol).FormulaR1C1 = Format(Date, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
ws.Cells(lRow + 1, startCol).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Rent"
ws.Cells(lRow + 1, startCol).Offset(0, 2).Value = "$440.00"
ws.Cells(lRow + 1, startCol).Offset(0, 3).Value = "Checking(NF)"

End Sub
```

It returns a string for the Date so it will appear last in the pivot as well when you sort on oldest to newest on Date column.

Comment: I actually messed up, the pivot table is on another sheet. The "fixed" row is trying to be added to a normal table. I've tried and cannot get this code above to work for a normal table.

Comment: I have updated the code to run the same procedure based on a table being present. I have assumed in sheet 2 which you will need to change the name of. Also assumed table is called Table1. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Working on another project, can you explain to me the purpose of "AddressArr()"? And why is it set to 1 and 4 in various locations in this source? I'm assuming it stands for array, however I'm having trouble visualizing the array and index values of 1 and 4 and how they relate to the table.

Comment: The location (.Address) of the table will be stored in the format e.g.  $A$1:$B$4. You can tell straight away the startCol is A and the lastRow is 4. To parse these from the .Address string use the Split function which splits a string up using a specified character e.g. '$' and returns the split values in an array which I store in AddressArr. So Split($A$1:$B$4,"$") becomes 5 items in an array  "", "A", "1", "B", "4". As arrays start at zero by default in vba you can access the startCol A at position 1 with AddressArr(1) and the lastRow 4 at position 4 I.e. AddressArr(4).

Comment: Should say position 2 for for startCol A which is AddressArr(1) and lastRow 4 at position 5 with AddressArr(4) as zero based index. Apologies.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense now. Thanks!